# Filtering array value of object within objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, filter

Let's say I have a whole database like this of 10000 cards and I'm trying to filter them on the `banlist_info.ban_ocg === "Forbidden"`

```
    {
        id: 15341821,
        name: 'Dandylion',
        type: 'Effect Monster',
        desc: 'If this card is sent to the Graveyard: Special Summon 2 "Fluff Tokens" (Plant-Type/WIND/Level 1/ATK 0/DEF 0) in Defense Position. These Tokens cannot be Tributed for a Tribute Summon during the turn they are Special Summoned.',
        atk: 300,
        def: 300,
        level: 3,
        race: 'Plant',
        attribute: 'EARTH',
        banlist_info: { ban_tcg: 'Forbidden', ban_ocg: 'Forbidden', ban_md: 'Forbidden' },
      },
      {
        id: 43694650,
        name: 'Danger!? Jackalope?',
        type: 'Effect Monster',
        desc: 'You can reveal this card in your hand; your opponent randomly chooses 1 card from your entire hand, then you discard the chosen card. Then, if the discarded card was not "Danger!? Jackalope?", Special Summon 1 "Danger!? Jackalope?" from your hand, and if you do, draw 1
     card. If this card is discarded: You can Special Summon 1 "Danger!" monster from your Deck in Defense Position, except "Danger!? Jackalope?". You can only use this effect of "Danger!? Jackalope?" once per turn.',
        atk: 500,
        def: 2000,
        level: 3,
        race: 'Beast',
        attribute: 'DARK',
        archetype: 'Danger!',
        banlist_info: { ban_tcg: 'Limited 1', ban_md: 'Limited 2' },
      },
      {
        id: 101111063,
        name: "Abyss Actors' Dress Rehearsal",
        type: 'Spell Card',
        desc: 'At the start of your Main Phase 1: Add 1 "Abyss Actor" card and 1 "Abyss Script" Spell from your Deck to your hand, also you cannot Pendulum Summon monsters for the rest of this turn after this card resolves, except "Abyss Actor" monsters.',
        race: 'Normal',
        archetype: 'Abyss Actor',
      },
```

I've tried :

```
filteredCards = await filteredCards.filter(o => o.banlist_info.ban_ocg === "Forbidden")
```

This however gives me the error:

```
            filteredCards = await filteredCards.filter(o => o.banlist_info.ban_ocg === "Forbidden");
                                                                           ^
    
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ban_ocg')
```

I've also tried:

```
filteredCards = await filteredCards.filter(o => o.banlist_info.filter(object => object.ban_ocg === "Forbidden"));
```

Which gives me the error:

```
filteredCards = await filteredCards.filter(o => o.banlist_info.filter(object => object.ban_ocg === "Forbidden"));
                                                                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')
```

and also :

```
filteredCards = await filteredCards.filter(o => o.banlist_info.some(object => object.ban_ocg === "Forbidden"));
```

Which just gave me another `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'some')`

How can I filter my cards by the Object within the object?

Comment: I mean yeah I do understand that it doesn't work due to there being no `.ban_ocg` in some items of the database. I just didn't know how else I would filter it. Someone below has posted a good answer though which was to add a `?` after the `banlist_info` which fixed my problem.

Comment: _“due to there being no `.ban_ocg` in some items”_ — No! Read the error message very carefully. _“Cannot read properties of `undefined` (reading '`ban_ocg`')”_ — You cannot make JavaScript read properties from something that has the value `undefined`, or shorter: you cannot make JavaScript read properties _**of**_ `undefined`. The error message tells you that this was encountered while trying to read `ban_ocg` in the expression `o.banlist_info.ban_ocg`. JavaScript cannot read the property `ban_ocg` _**of**_ `undefined`. **This means `o.banlist_info` is `undefined`**, not `.ban_ocg`.

Comment: Oooh, that makes more sense. Thank you I'm still somewhat new to coding xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ban_ocg')
```

That is because some of your JSONs do not have the properties you are trying to access.

Try with the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (?.)

```js
const data = [ { id: 15341821, name: "Dandylion", type: "Effect Monster", desc: 'If this card is sent to the Graveyard: Special Summon 2 "Fluff Tokens" (Plant-Type/WIND/Level 1/ATK 0/DEF 0) in Defense Position. These Tokens cannot be Tributed for a Tribute Summon during the turn they are Special Summoned.', atk: 300, def: 300, level: 3, race: "Plant", attribute: "EARTH", banlist_info: { ban_tcg: "Forbidden", ban_ocg: "Forbidden", ban_md: "Forbidden", }, }, { id: 43694650, name: "Danger!? Jackalope?", type: "Effect Monster", desc: 'You can reveal this card in your hand; your opponent randomly chooses 1 card from your entire hand, then you discard the chosen card. Then, if the discarded card was not "Danger!? Jackalope?", Special Summon 1 "Danger!? Jackalope?" from your hand, and if you do, draw 1 card. If this card is discarded: You can Special Summon 1 "Danger!" monster from your Deck in Defense Position, except "Danger!? Jackalope?". You can only use this effect of "Danger!? Jackalope?" once per turn.', atk: 500, def: 2000, level: 3, race: "Beast", attribute: "DARK", archetype: "Danger!", banlist_info: { ban_tcg: "Limited 1", ban_md: "Limited 2" }, }, { id: 101111063, name: "Abyss Actors' Dress Rehearsal", type: "Spell Card", desc: 'At the start of your Main Phase 1: Add 1 "Abyss Actor" card and 1 "Abyss Script" Spell from your Deck to your hand, also you cannot Pendulum Summon monsters for the rest of this turn after this card resolves, except "Abyss Actor" monsters.', race: "Normal", archetype: "Abyss Actor", }, ];

const filteredCards = data.filter(o => o.banlist_info?.ban_ocg === "Forbidden")

console.log(filteredCards)
```

Comment: You don't need `?` on the `o` just on `banlist_info`.

Comment: @Andy, Yes. updated the answer. unless there are no null or undefined entries in the array itself